# agGrid - Set formatter for Row instead of Column

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

I'm using ag-Grid to display a financial report in the following format

```
| Info                  | Value         |
|-----------------------|---------------|
| Sales                 |       $ 10M   |
| (-) Production Costs  |        $ 1M   |
| (-) Production Taxes  |        $ 1M   |
| (=) Margin            |        $ 8M   |
|  % Profit             |         10%   |
```

Notice how the `Value` column can have different formats for different rows.
I would like to know if there is a way to set different formatters for each row, instead of setting it to the ColumnDef?

Thanks

Comment: does the below answer solve your problem? If so could you accept it so other users having the same question can be benefited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the value formatter for "value" column

```
colDef.valueFormatter = function(params) {
  if(params.data["Info"] == "% Profit"){
      return params.value + "%";
  }
  else{
      return '$' + params.value;
  }
}
```